# Is there a difference between Response::json and implied json?

Tags: php, json, laravel, model

In Laravel 4, I can create a JSON response by using `return Response::json( $model );`. By default, I can also simply do `return $model;` as well.

Are there any benefits to using `Response::json` over implicitly calling `$model->toJson()`?

Answer (score 0):

Returning `return $model` should return a [collection](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#collections) which has a lot of built in functionality. `$model->toJson()` will strip it down to just a json file.

Edit: I answered this as returning the model to the controller rather than to be rendered. Sent to the renderer, I believe both `Response::json` and `$model->toJson()` do the same thing but `Response::json` is for data that is not in a collection.

Some resources to help with what a collection can do:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#collections

https://laracasts.com/lessons/arrays-on-steroids

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you use `return Response::json()`, it's also setting return headers, probably `Content-type: text/javascript`.

This way, the calling script knows that it's getting back javascript before it even starts to read the return body.  Sometimes, it might be possible for the script which ran your function to behave differently or parse the response body differently depending on the content type it gets back.